# Why is json_decode output always null?

Tags: php, json

i have an issue where when i do a **return $record** in my function below i get valid json in postman pretty view but if i try print_r($record) i have a null at the end of the json.

Then when i try to **json_decode** the out put is always **null** for some reason.

If anyone has any ideas why this might be happening i am greatful for your input.

Thanks

```
function webhook_listener($request_data){
        $client = new ZohoCRMClient('Contacts', 'API key Here');

        $parameters = $request_data->get_params();

        if( !isset( $parameters['contactId'] ) || empty($parameters['contactId']) ){
            file_put_contents(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'invalid.txt', 'No parameter found');
            return array( 'error' => 'no_parameter_given' );
        }else{
            $companyid = $parameters['contactId'];

            //file_put_contents(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'crm.txt', $parameters);

            $record = $client->getRecordById()->id($companyid)->request();

            $record = json_decode($record);

            $error = json_last_error();
            if ($error !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
                throw new RuntimeException("JSON decode error: $error");
            }

            echo $company = $record[1]['data']['Company'];

        }

    }
```

**JSON:**

```
{"1":{"index":1,"data":{"CONTACTID":"3345923000000546002","SMOWNERID":"3345923000000158021","Contact Owner":"Frank Rosa","First Name":"Administrator","Last Name":"Ian","Email":"poojarajan3ellc@gmail.com","Created Time":"2018-09-19 14:32:35","Modified Time":"2018-09-20 02:48:51","Full Name":"Administrator Ian","Description":"Equity and Empowerment through Education. It is the Mission of 3e LLC to promote equity and empowerment for all students through engaging professional development for educators and parents, one-on-one coaching for teacher efficacy, and mentoring services for youth to promote enrichment and success. For the empowered, we offer editing, transcribing, and ghostwriting services to ensure your voice is heard.","Last Activity Time":"2018-09-20 02:48:51","Instagram Url":"http:\/\/www.instagram.com\/3e_llc","Company":"3ELLC","Website":"https:\/\/www.3ellc.org","Phone_1":"(727) 420-1050","Full Address":"2152 Arcadia Rd, Holiday, FL 34690, USA","Facebook Url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/3eLLC\/","Logo Url":"https:\/\/dev.energypages.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/05\/header-logo-57.png","Twitter Url":"http:\/\/www.twitter.com\/3e_llc","Membership Level":"Basic","Select Service":"Technology","User ID":"347"}}}
```

**var_dump output:**

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  object(CristianPontes\ZohoCRMClient\Response\Record)#2068 (2) {
    ["index"]=>
    int(1)
    ["data"]=>
    array(22) {
      ["CONTACTID"]=>
      string(19) "3345923000000546002"
      ["SMOWNERID"]=>
      string(19) "3345923000000158021"
      ["Contact Owner"]=>
      string(10) "Frank Rosa"
      ["First Name"]=>
      string(13) "Administrator"
      ["Last Name"]=>
      string(3) "Ian"
      ["Email"]=>
      string(25) "poojarajan3ellc@gmail.com"
      ["Created Time"]=>
      string(19) "2018-09-19 14:32:35"
      ["Modified Time"]=>
      string(19) "2018-09-20 02:48:51"
      ["Full Name"]=>
      string(17) "Administrator Ian"
      ["Description"]=>
      string(407) "Equity and Empowerment through Education. It is the Mission of 3e LLC to promote equity and empowerment for all students through engaging professional development for educators and parents, one-on-one coaching for teacher efficacy, and mentoring services for youth to promote enrichment and success. For the empowered, we offer editing, transcribing, and ghostwriting services to ensure your voice is heard."
      ["Last Activity Time"]=>
      string(19) "2018-09-20 02:48:51"
      ["Instagram Url"]=>
      string(31) "http://www.instagram.com/3e_llc"
      ["Company"]=>
      string(5) "3ELLC"
      ["Website"]=>
      string(21) "https://www.3ellc.org"
      ["Phone_1"]=>
      string(14) "(727) 420-1050"
      ["Full Address"]=>
      string(39) "2152 Arcadia Rd, Holiday, FL 34690, USA"
      ["Facebook Url"]=>
      string(30) "http://www.facebook.com/3eLLC/"
      ["Logo Url"]=>
      string(73) "https://dev.energypages.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/header-logo-57.png"
      ["Twitter Url"]=>
      string(29) "http://www.twitter.com/3e_llc"
      ["Membership Level"]=>
      string(5) "Basic"
      ["Select Service"]=>
      string(10) "Technology"
      ["User ID"]=>
      string(3) "347"
    }
  }
}
null
```

Output above is the raw view in postman. and in pretty view i got this error (Unexpected 'a')

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: Have you logged the value of `$client->getRecordById()->id($companyid)->request()` somewhere?

Comment: `json_decode()` returns an object and you're trying to access the data as an array, you need to pass `true` as the second argument if you want an associative array

Comment: you should be using an array instead

Comment: @ceejayoz if i return $client->getRecordById()->id($companyid)->request() i get the json in my post but if i do a echo i get an (Arraynull)

Comment: @billyonecan i still get an output of null with the true argument

Comment: @LarsStegelitz how do i format this into an array?

Comment: [works fine here](https://3v4l.org/SH9TO)

Comment: Turn on error_reporting (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/845034).

Comment: I suspect if you do `var_dump($client->getRecordById()->id($companyid)->request());` you'll see your problem.

Comment: @miken32 i updated my post with the output

Comment: Does that look like something that `json_decode` can make sense of?

Comment: Also I hope that isn't live client data...

Comment: @miken32 how can i convert this to work with json_decode?

Comment: I guess that would be a question for the documentation of whatever library is providing the data.

Comment: @miken32 it's dummy data and will be removed from the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the answers here on how to parse jSON were correct. But i was using a php library for my link to zoho which handles the data differently, so i had to do a foreach on my response from the API then json_encode() the data and json_decode() to get the values.

Library i am using: https://github.com/cristianpontes/zoho-crm-client-php

```
foreach($record as $records){
            $payload = $records->getData();
            $payload = json_encode($payload);
            $payload = json_decode($payload, true);

            $error = json_last_error();
            if ($error !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
                throw new RuntimeException("JSON decode error: $error");
            }

            $company = $payload['Company'];
}
```

Thanks to everyone that helped especially @miken32